# What is the best way to create connect redis master using JedisSentinalPool?

Tags: redis, jedis, redis-cluster, sentinel, redis-sentinel

I am using java Jedis client to connect redis sentinal deployment. I deployed redis sentinel in my kubernetes cluster. To insert data in redis, we need to get the current redis master and then insert the data.

Here is my sample Code snippet.

```
public class RedisCacheStore {
        private Jedis jedis = null;
        private static RedisCacheStore instance = null;
        private static final Object mutex = new Object();
        private JedisSentinelPool jedisSentinal = null;
    
        private RedisCacheStore( ) {
            initRedisConnection();
        }
        
        private void initRedisConnection() {
            try {
                redisHostName = System.getenv("REDIS_HOST");
                redisSentinalPort = System.getenv("REDIS_SENTINAL_PORT") ;
                redisUserName = System.getenv("REDIS_USERNAME");
                redisPassword = System.getenv("REDIS_PASSWORD");
                
                Set<String> sentinals = new HashSet<>();
                sentinals.add("redis:26379");
                jedisSentinal = new JedisSentinelPool("mymaster", sentinals, "default", "pass@123");
                
                new RedisMasterDiscovery().start();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        private class RedisMasterDiscovery extends Thread {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                jedis = jedisSentinal.getResource();
                System.out.println("Successfully initiated redis connection.");
            }
        }
    
        public static RedisCacheStore getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized (mutex) {
                    instance = new RedisCacheStore();
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
        
        public String get(String key) throws Exception {
            jedis.get(key);
        }

        public boolean put(String key, String value) throws Exception {
            jedis.set(key, value);
        }
}
```

Is this efficient way to get current master from sentinal and insert data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not. Your app is using only single connection for all operations! That is not stable.

Using try-with-resources will solve that:

```java
public String get(String key) throws Exception {
   try(var jedis = jedisSentinal.getResource()) {
      jedis.get(key);
   }
}

public boolean put(String key, String value) throws Exception {
   try(var jedis = jedisSentinal.getResource()) {
      jedis.set(key, value);
   }
}
```

Or just use [JedisSentineled](https://javadoc.io/static/redis.clients/jedis/5.2.0-alpha2/redis/clients/jedis/JedisSentineled.html)